# How can I solve "Error:Could not download gradle-core.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3): No cached version available for offline mode"

Tags: android, android-studio

> Error:Could not download gradle-core.jar
>   (com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3): No cached version
>   available for offline mode

I am using Android Studio 2.3. This error appears after new update.

Comment: go online to download

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403444/could-not-resolve-com-android-tools-buildgradle2-2-3)

Answer (score 3):

You can disable `offline work` in the gradle settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me too. Here's what I did:

1 - `Go to Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment option -> Instant Run`

2 - Uncheck `Enable instant run to hot swap code`

3 - Clean project

4 - Check `Enable instant run to hot swap code` and build again.

Worked for me, hope it is a fix for everyone facing the same issue.

Comment: The checkbox 'Enable instant run to hot swap code'  is  Inactive for me  Android Studio 3.1.1

Comment: @SamNikzad I'm not sure how I made it active then, but maybe [this helps](https://github.com/ftctechnh/ftc_app/wiki/Disabling-Android-Studio-Instant-Run)

Answer (score 0):

Open you android studio path, then open path:

```
/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/
```

Then, `gradle-core-2.2.3.jar` should appear, like this:

```
/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/2.2.3/gradle-core-2.2.3.jar.
```

If not, you will have to [download it](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle-core) and put it at there.