# React native build-failed Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, gradle, npm

Trying to generate apk android using React-native :
command :react-native run-android 
see the below error : 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'AwesomeProject'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
  >   Required by:
  >   project :
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tool
  >   /build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/buil
  >   /gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
  >   Connection reset

BUILD FAILED
Please help me out to solve this issue struggling alot .

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
 
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15756

Comment: Tried to add google() to build.gradle ,Will get the error in windows                          * Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\amundra\Documents\ReactNative\AwesomeProject\android\build.
gradle' line: 6

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'AwesomeProject'.
> Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container of typ
e org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.

* Try:

Can you please help me to solve this . I think so because of this only build failing

Comment: checkout this - It may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403444/could-not-resolve-com-android-tools-buildgradle2-2-3

Comment: Tried this also not helping .Even I reset the cache not working . My android studio is 3.1 .