# Why my Gradle project sync fails every time I start a new project?

Tags: android, gradle

Every time I create a new project I get this error related to resolution of Gradle build and I always have to go to Settings and then change the Gradle version to fix the situation. I am unable to figure out the root cause behind this.[image]

I don't want to do the same process again and again.

Comment: Maybe Gradle is in offline mode? Or Iis your connection working?

Comment: There is no issue with internet connection

Comment: Check if it's using offline mode

Comment: I assume you didn't change any configuration after creating new project, see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42676735/11880323